Tomcat default redirect path for System.err/out in Windows
I try to log some dev information via System.err.println and run my program as a service on Windows server. But after my application is launched I can't find my logs in any tomcat file. For unix based systems tomcat creates Catalina.out file but in Windows this file has a different path.
I've found, that this messages could be present in
\logs\stderr.log  
\logs\stdout.log

files, but I don't have this files.
What is default redirect file path in Windows for System.err/out messages?

.out files are created when Tomcat runs as a daemon without console when you run bin/startup.sh and shutdown by bin/shutdown.sh, Windows last time I checked also has similar behaviour. By default std out and std err are directed to console but tomcat always does not log every thing to console. For than the logging properties need to be changed.
